# Is there a limit to the complexity of a type to be inferred by Lombok's val?

Tags: gradle, lombok

I have a Data Access Object written using jOOQ and it returns a rather complex type signature:

```
Map<Record, Result<Record14<String, Integer, String, String, String, String, String, String, Integer, String, Boolean, Boolean, Integer, Boolean>>> result = create....
```

I tried to replace it with Lombok's "val"

```
val result = create....
```

**This works when I run/compile from Eclipse...** When I try to compile within Gradle, I get:

```
UpdatesDAO.java:307: error: incompatible types
            .fetchGroups(key);
                        ^
  required: val
  found: Map<Record,Result<Record14<String,Integer,String,String,String,String,String,String,Integer,String,Boolean,Boolean,Integer,Boolean>>>
```

Can anyone tell me why it would work in Gradle for simpler types, but not for more complex types? I have other places in this same project which look something like:

```
val records = dao.getDatastoreById(id); // Returns a type of List<Datastore>
```

and they work just fine, even when compiled with Gradle... Am I missing something?

FYI: Lombok version = 1.14.8, Gradle version 2.2.1

I have tried lombok==1.14.6, Gradle version 2.2.0

I have also tried with both Java 8 and Java 7, both OpenJDK and Oracle JDK

Comment: Question:  why do you require fourteen generic types?  This is a code smell more than anything...

Comment: I suppose you would have to bring that up with the jOOQ people and how they do their database interactions... Regardless of if it is a code smell, it makes little sense that it would work when compiling from Eclipse and does not work when compiling from Gradle..

Comment: @Makoto: Often, those types are only used behind the scenes in jOOQ's fluent API, and inferred by the compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a conflict between jOOQ's DSL and lombok.. The jOOQ DSL has a method "val" which will cause a conflict when imported statically:

```
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.val;
```

If you are using that "val" method via a static import it will break lombok's "val" implementation. Removing that static import and using "DSL.val()" instead resolved the issue for me.

More information available at: https://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=762